# Is there a way to manually change raspberry pi's audio setting to built-in digital?

Tags: audio

As soon as I full-upgraded my pi, my sound has not been working on any apps (including chromium). I have tried to type in terminal code to stop it, but have had no such luck. The only app that still plays audio is my VLC media player, in which before I must manually change my audio settings from 'built-in analog' to 'built-in digital'. Is there any way to set my default sound to be digital?

Comment: Abandoned post by Unregistered user.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely the pulseaudio configuration that lingers.

On my Raspberry Pi with similar problem I just had to reset the daemon and it started defaulting to the digital output

> pulseaudio --kill
>
> pulseaudio --start

Otherwise you might have to explicitly set the default.

At this point I'm guessing because I didn't have to go through this myself

**1: Get the sink numbers**

```
pacmd list-sinks
```

Lets say the one you want is index 0

**2: Set the default**

```
pacmd set-default-sink 0
```

Docs say you could use the name instead of index, which might be more robust.

If the default doesn't stick you may have to tinker with /etc/pulse/client.conf

There is a set default line in there

Hope that helps